# Removing the margin of a Button on Android using NativeScript

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

In a NativeScript app I have a Button with margin set to `0`, yet there is still a small margin on Android.

Comment: please remove android tag if your question is not related to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This additional "margin" is part of Androids Material Design. It cannot be removed by using the margin property, because it is actually a border – though setting the `border-width: 0` won't help either. Instead, simply dye the border to fit the background color:

```css
Button {
  border-width: 1;
  background-color: green;
  border-color: green;
}
```

See here for more information: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2626#issuecomment-261493611